# How to set simple passwords on Azure AD

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, password-protection

I support primary schools thats Children aged 4 to 10 and recently we have started migrating to Azure AD
But we need to set simple passwords for the Student Accounts that the children will remember.

We were managing using PowerShell
Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $user.UserPrincipalName -StrongPasswordRequired $False
Set-MsolUserPassword -UserPrincipalName $user.UserPrincipalName -NewPassword $Password -ForceChangePassword $False
Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $user.UserPrincipalName –PasswordNeverExpires $True

But this has stopped working now giving the error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bxgmi.png)

Microsoft have said it can't be done....

Has anyone managed to bypass the password complexity requirement..

Comment: As Xkcd reminded us, passwords can be high entropy but easy to remember.  https://xkcd.com/936/

Answer (score 0):

I use this script to create student accounts in Azure, with simple passwords:

```
#This script will create 20 student users in Azure AD

$PasswordProfile = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.PasswordProfile
$PasswordProfile.Password = 'Mysecretpassword2022'
$passwordProfile.ForceChangePasswordNextLogin = $false


#Create User
1..20 | % {New-AzureADUser -DisplayName "student$_" -PasswordProfile $PasswordProfile -UserPrincipalName "student$_@xxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com" -AccountEnabled $true -MailNickName "student$_" -PasswordPolicies "DisablePasswordExpiration"} | Select-Object ObjectId, DisplayName, UserPrincipalName
```

Perhaps it can help?

Comment: Thanks for this but thats not a simple password. we need to set things they will remember including the reception class 4 year olds "123abc" type of thing that will fail the password complexity test from the policy

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation for resetting Office365](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/add-users/reset-passwords?view=o365-worldwide#set-strong-passwords), there might be a new process for disabling strong passwords, which I hope will apply to you.

1. Start by installing the [Microsoft Graph PowerShell SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/installation?view=graph-powershell-1.0):
   `Install-Module Microsoft.Graph -Scope CurrentUser`
2. Connect to MS Graph:
   `Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "User.Read.All"`
3. Disable Strong Passwords:
   `Update-MgUser -UserId $user.UserPrincipalName -PasswordPolicies "DisableStrongPassword"`

Proceed with the rest of your commands, you might need to do some testing to find out which ones you still require, assuming this works at all.

```
Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $user.UserPrincipalName -StrongPasswordRequired $False
Set-MsolUserPassword -UserPrincipalName $user.UserPrincipalName -NewPassword $Password -ForceChangePassword $False
Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $user.UserPrincipalName –PasswordNeverExpires $True
```

Alternatively... if you can't find a way to disable strong passwords, it might be worth building your own list of easy words children know and constructing simple, but technically complex passwords for them, something like:

- apple-box-car
- cat-grass-sky
- mouse-book-water

Or if dashes are too much, you can use numbers:

- apple1box2car
- cat1grass2sky
- mouse1book2water

etc. whether or not this is actually simple to a four year old, I think you'd need to try it out to know.

Comment: Thanks for this but that is what I've been using but has stopped working now.. I was hoping that there would be another hidden function that would magically help... :)